# Unexpected value change after savechanges()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, savechanges

I'm trying to save a value on a DB based on Entity Framework via visual studio 2013 in c#.

I've got to save on the DB auction datas. Each auction has its own id, an int, that is its primary key.

When i try to add an auction on the db i do  the following:

```
using(var c = new AuctionSiteContext(ConnectionString)
{
var auction = new Database.Auction
       {
              Id = auctionId,    //auctionId=0
              /*
              other stuff
              */
       };
c.Auctions.Add(auction);
c.SaveChanges();
}
```

The problem is that auctionId is set to 0 and i checked it via debugger, but when i do the saveChanges(); and control again the value of that only auction on the site its Id has been changed to 1.

I don't honestly understand why savechanges() invokation can change that value because there are no limitations in the auction column on the db, i mean, why can't it be simply 0?

It does so every time i add an auction, incrementing by one the id,  but all the other parameters remain the same.

**edit**: I decide to start the sequence from 0, that's what that means. But i even tried to start from 1, meaning that the first auction has id=1, but then after the savechanges it became 2.

Comment: What does `Id=0` actually mean?? Sounds kinda like a bad architectural/design decision...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case where the Key field is an Integer, Code First defaults to DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity. So, if you want to add your own  Id values you need to configure your entity class. There are two ways to do that:

Using **[Data Annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx)**:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Using **[Fluent Api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx)**:

In your Context, override the method OnModelCreating and do this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<Auction>()
  .HasKey(t => t.Id)
  .Property(t => t.Id)
  .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
}
```

Comment: Doing the first way did the trick! That's mean that the key, if is an int, is set automatically to be autoincrement?
Because i tried to not set manually the id and effectively it was added automatically.

Answer (score 5):

This can happen if `Id` is an auto-increment column in your database. When you save it to the database, the database puts its own value into that column, and your EntityFramework model automatically updates accordingly.

Comment: Where can i check if it is auto-increment?

Comment: @Sanci If you have access to the database check the column type to see if it is an Identity column (SQL Server). You can also check the entities for the DB and see if it is `DatabaseGenerated`

Comment: Thanks AJ, though in my case it was .HasDefaultValueSql in DbContext, you're pointed me on a right way <3